# Add A New Property To A Third Party Control

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, controls

I am working with dev ex controls and on a menu bar item there isnt a property for setting the button to Visible or not Not Visible.

Can you add properties like this to pre made controls? If so how would you do it?

Comment: Is there any public way on the control to set the visibility besides a property... like a method?

Comment: Can you give me a sample, I dont see how you can create a visible-not visible behavior if it isnt available to you.

Comment: What I am asking is if there is **ANY** publicly accessible way to control visibility. `SetControlVisiblity(false)` or something like that. If there is, then you can create an extension method. If not, but there is a protected member, then you could created a derived class and expose that property yourself. Otherwise, you are just out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If allowed (control class not marked as sealed),  you should create another control that inherits from your dev ex control in order to add extra properties.

Comment: Can you give me a sample, I dont see how you can create a visible-not visible behavior if it isnt available to you.

Comment: Well, the control has a lot of protected methods and properties (not visible for class consumers). When you inherits, you'll have access to them. I can't say 100% sure that you'll able to achieve what you want since I don't know those controls but I think it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative if you can use inheritance.

You can create [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) that will act like properties.

**GetCompanyName()**

**SetCompanyName()**

After all, properties are language shortcut to create them at compilation ;)